# Find the number of 3 element subsets of the set {1, 2, …, 10}, in which the least element is 3 or the greatest element is 7.

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I tried using the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion (PIE) but couldn't find a way through.

Comment: Why did your PIE fail? Did you not know which sets to consider?Or were you unable to compute the size of the sets that you did find through PIE? Take a simpler example : just try to find the number of subsets whose minimal element is $3$. It is a simpler exercise, and if you get the logic for it right (tell me and I will tell you if you got it right), then you can proceed to this question.

Comment: The no. of 3-element subsets are 21.

Comment: Are you telling me that $21$ is the answer to the question? That is too few : check the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The number of subsets with least element $3$ is $\binom72$, for there are $7$ elements greater than $3$ and we must pick two from them to complete the subset ($3$ itself is fixed). Similarly, the number of subsets with greatest element $7$ is $\binom62$. Then the number of subsets satisfying both conditions is $3$, since the middle element can only be $4,5,6$.

By inclusion/exclusion, the final answer is $\binom72+\binom62-3=21+15-3=33$.